# PHP: Passwords with Special Characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, passwords

I can't seem to come up with the right way to work with passwords in PHP. I'm hashing and using a salt when it comes to storing, but I'm trying to get the basic password down

```
stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]));
```

I'm assuming some users will use passwords with "!@#$%^..." etc.
I can imagine users using a password like `<b>lulz</b>"u'mad?`.

How can I include these special characters in my password variable?

Comment: I wouldn't use stripslashes on any data being that's not going to be re-outputted as HTML.

Comment: you shouldnt concern yourself with that. you should just salt and hash the original value.

Comment: You don't need to do *anything* to the input before you hash it.

Comment: why do you escape the string? If you hash it before storing it cannot containt anything you don't want it to?

Comment: When using hashs with salt, why you think about special characters? The hashed string only contains alpha-characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do any kind of escaping or stripping here.<sup>*</sup>  Just something like `$hashed = my_favourite_hash($_POST["password"] . $salt)` should be fine.<sup>†</sup>  Any sane hashing function should return a string of alphanumeric characters, none of which need escaping.

Anyway, you should be using prepared statements for your SQL queries, so there's no chance of SQL injection, etc.

---

<sub>* Assuming that you don't have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled (and you really shouldn't!).</sub>

† Substitute your preferred hash function for `my_favourite_hash` here.

Comment: I'm guessing the sub-text was to ward off "{hash_algo} isn't safe!!" type comments. Good call :)

Comment: The point of stripslashes() and mysql_real_escape_string() is to make sure that you aren't passing anything to your queries that could be mistaken for something other than data.  The hashing should turn anything you send it into strictly string data.

Answer (score 3):

Storing password in plain text format is extremely harmful. Instead you should store a hash of that password in database. If password is hashed, there is no limitation for the characters it might contain.

To create said hash I would recommend for you to use [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function. Preferably using SHA512 or BLOWFISH algorithm.

Additionally, i would recommend for you to stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions (which are in the process of being deprecated) and learn how to utilize [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) with prepared statements.